# Discrete Mathematics Recursion

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

A bacteria colony begins with $6$ individuals and doubles in size every hour. Write down a recurrence for a population at the beginning of hour n, and solve it. How many hours elapse until the population exceeds one million?

This is what I wrote: $a_n=2a_{n-1}$ for $\forall n\ge 1$ where our $a_0=6$ (sorry I don't know how to write it properly)

However the solution continues with : We know $a_0 = 1$, so: 
$a_n = 2a_{n−1} = 2^2a_{n−2} = 2^3a_{n−3} = \cdots = 2^na_0 = 6\cdot 2^n$. This is the part which I do not understand. Can someone explain it to me?

Thank you!

Comment: I've edited it. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I think the solution was supposed to continue with "We know $a_0 = 6$".

Comment: tarit actually the solution was an = 2an−1 = 22an−1 = 23an−2 = ... = 2na0 = 6·2n.
 which may be wrong

Answer (score 1):

> We know $a_0=1$

Here $a_0=6$. $a_n=2a_{n-1}$ is called recurrence relation, where $n$th term is related to $(n-1)$ th term by the given relation. Here $n$ is a variable which can take values $\ge 1$. Hence, we can also write $a_{n-1}=2a_{n-2}$ and $a_{n-2}=2a_{n-3}$ and so on upto $a_1=2a_0$(minimum value of $n$ can be $1$).

So, putting the values back, we can say, $$a_n=2a_{n-1}=2\cdot (2a_{n-2})=2^2a_{n-2}\\=2^2\cdot (2a_{n-3})=2^3a_{n-3}$$
 and in general, $a_n=2^ka_{n-k}$ where $1\le k\le n$. So, finally you will have $a_n= 2^na_0=6\cdot 2^n$, as $a_0=6$. Have you understood now?

Comment: So the solution given by my teacher is wrong right?

Comment: @Flea What was your teacher's solution?

Comment: How did you come up with an=2^na0=6*2^n?

Comment: an = 2an−1, n ≥ 1
We know a0 = 1, so: 
an = 2an−1 = 2^2an−1 = 2^3an−2 = ... = 2na0 = 6·2n.
Therefore: 
an = 6·2n ∀n ≥ 0.

Comment: @Flea $a_n$ can be written as $2^ka{n-k}$, have you understood that? Then just put $k=n$, you will get $a_n=2^na_0$.

Comment: Yes I have understood thanks

Comment: @Flea Welcome :) If it explained your query, you can accept this question by clicking the tick mark left of the answer